# Ansible Copy module - Copy skipping the first 9 lines of the source file

Tags: ansible

I am wondering if the Ansible if I can use the copy module to Copy the content of the source path skipping the first 9 lines and At dest path, skipping the first 9 lines as well..

The need is to always use the source file as the "master file" because that file is changing every day. So I want to synchronize that file to a list of hosts in my inventory, but as I said, skipping the first 9 lines which are different in each server.

Thanks in advance.

Bernardo.

Comment: Jinja may be useful 
 for your use case: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html

Comment: [`blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) in combination with [`file` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/file.html) for the content might do the trick.

Comment: @Zeitounator, Thank you for tip. The combination you suggested did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have internally synced the file I wanted to send to the other servers to use it on the playbook. The playbook below is the one that worked for me.
I also create a fact to each server with the path to the file I wanted to synchronize. The path is different in each server.

```
---
- hosts: macros
  vars:
  macrosToSync: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/ansible/macrosToSync') }}"
  tasks:
- name: Insert macros
  blockinfile:
    path: "{{ ansible_facts.ansible_local.sitename.siteVars.path }}"
    insertafter: "# set your own macros here:"
    block: |
      {{ macrosToSync }}
 ...
```